# Record browser tests for Laravel Dusk chromedriver

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing automated tests for a PHP Laravel application with Dusk.

I am writing tests in tests/Browser/ folder this way:

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit( '/admin' )
                ->type('login', 'mylogin')
                ->type('password', 'mypassword')
                ->press('Sign In')
                ->pause(1000)
                ->assertSee('Welcome on admin dashboard !');
                ->visit( '/admin/products/new' )
                ->type('name', 'Product 1')
                ...
```

My question is: Is there a way to generate this files ? I need something like a browser plugin. I will navigate and create some products on my application. Then i want to replay this scenario in my tests.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Laravel test Tools Chrome extension could that be any use? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laravel-testtools/ddieaepnbjhgcbddafciempnibnfnakl?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Test Tools extension could assist you.

Github repo: https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-testtools

Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laravel-testtools/ddieaepnbjhgcbddafciempnibnfnakl?hl=en

This will help you build up tests without manually writing the code for each test.